# Modelling Correlated Predictors

Tags: regression, correlation, least-squares

Say I have three (financial) variables: $X_1, X_2$ (predictors) and $Y$ (dependent variable). I suspect that both have an effect on $Y$, but I also suspect that $X_1$ has an effect on $X_2$ and that they are therefore correlated.

With that in mind, it is probably inadvisable to put both predictors into a regression as they are correlated and this will result in unstable estimates of the regression parameters.

But, I am interested in both of their effects on $Y$ and would like to examine them.

What would be the correct way to approach this problem? I thought of the following regression:

$Y$ ~ $\alpha + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2(X_2 - X_1)$

The logic is that I am capturing the effect of $X_1$, and the effect of $X_2$ that isn't due to $X_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Simply subtracting X1 from X2 is going to give you what you are interested in.  This just creates a new variable where the associated beta coefficient will then tell you the effect that the difference in X2 and X1 gives on the expected value of the response.

*Instead, try regressing X2 on the residuals left behind from a simple regression that uses only X1 as the original predictor.*  That will tell you how much variance X2 explains after accounting for X1 .

This is a similar process to what drives certain [step-wise variable selection methods](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_23.0.0/spss/base/linear_regression_methods.html).  A forward step-wise selection starts by regressing each individual predictor that is present against the Y variable to determine which single predictor actually captures the most variation in Y.  Call the winning predictor X1 for simplicity.  Once X1 has been selected as a feature to keep, the algorithm continues by regressing the remaining predictors against the *residuals* left behind from fitting X1; it finds the predictor (call it X2), that best explains the variance in these *residuals*.  The process of fitting to successive residuals continues until a pre-determined number of predictors are found, or when the significance of the predictor drops below a pre-defined significance level.

Comment: I haven't calculated these quantities yet - I wanted to approach it not being biased by the data. Let's assume that they are correlated (say 0.5) and that I'm still interested in both of their effects on Y. I'm not interested in variable selection techniques because I know a priori that I'm interested in these variables.

Comment: I was simply saying the methods that drive the variable selection techniques may be of use to you in your current situation.  Try regressing on the residuals after your initial simple regression (say using X1 as your predictor), and that will tell you how much variance X2 explains after accounting for X1.

Comment: Add the "Try regressing on the residuals after your initial simple regression (say using X1 as your predictor), and that will tell you how much variance X2 explains after accounting for X1." tip to your answer so i can mark as answer